# Use of emerald fonts in Ubuntu and locate font folder

Tags: fonts, ubuntu, linux, themes

I would like to use emerald fonts in my Beamer presentation (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/augie/)

As far I have understood, I have to download the emerald folder and to move the fonts in some other folder related to latex. In particular, it seems that I have to copy the directories "fonts" and "tex" to "~/Library/texmf/"

It works on my Mac OSX with MacTex installed as well. First, download the emerald zip file from ctan and unzip it. Second, copy the two dirs: fonts and tex to ~/Library/texmf/. The I should some staff as updmap and texhash.

First of all, I would like if the above mention procedure is correct for linux\ubuntu. Secondly, I would like how to locate the folder texmf in ubuntu. Lastly, Do you have other suggestion to install emerald.

This is the solution that I have found so fare:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\augiefamily}{%
  \fontfamily{augie}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaugie}{\augiefamily}


\augiefamily

\begin{document}
 
 
\begin{frame}{\augiefamily Example}
 hello
\end{frame}
 

\end{document}
```

As you can notice, I skip "emerald.sty". Unfortunately , I have to add "\augiefamily" everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TrueType or OpenType font, and I believe Augie does come in this format, you can save it in any of your system or user font directories, and LuaTeX or XeTeX should be able to find it. If you’re writing a `beamer` presentation, no publisher is stopping you from using modern fonts or LuaTeX.  That’s usually the simplest way.

I believe the latest TrueType version of Augie is [still up at the Internet Archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719055112/http://www.speakeasy.org/%7Eecf/alphabet.htm)

If you have a legacy font, or if you only want to use a font for TeX and not have it cluttering up any of your other font lists, you can find your local TeX tree with the command

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

On Ubuntu (and, I believe, the MacOS console), you can have the shell look this up for you, with something like

```
export TEXMFLOCAL=$(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)
```

and then use commands such as `cd $TEXMFLOCAL`.

I would recommend you do something like creating the subdirectories `$TEXMFLOCAL/emerald/fonts` and `$TEXMFLOCAL/emerald/tex`, because this keeps all the files in this package together.  TeX doesn’t care what subdirectory you put the files in.  If you just mingle all the files from all your packages in the same tree, it’s impossible to uninstall cleanly, and you run the risk of some other package with `fonts` and `tex` folders overwriting its files.

Whenever you install a new font in your local tex tree, you want to run

```
sudo texhash
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map
```

to update the file database and the font maps.  (If you have your own custom installation owned by an account named `tex`, this becomes `sudo -u tex -E texhash`, etc.)

#### In Beamer

Beamer defaults to using the sans-serif font.  To get it to use Augie, you would want to `\usefonttheme{serif}`.  You might also want to add the `[professionalfonts]` option to the `\documentclass`.

Comment: Thanks. The output of kpsewhich is "/usr/local/share/texmf". I have created a folder in texmf:  emerald. "emerald" is the unzip folder of emerald.zip from CTAN. As a consequence, emerald has as subfolder: tex, fonts, other and doc. However when I run "sudo updmap-sys" I get some errors. (no error with "sudo texhash"):

updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:  emerald.map (in /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

I think that I have to do something about map. What do you think?

Comment: In the folder I have the new file "ls-R". This is the output of sudo texhash. The problem is sudo updmap-sys

Comment: Ah, you might try, then, `sudo updmap-sys --enable-map=emerald.map`. You might need to give the absolute path, which you should be able to find (after running `texhash`) with `kpsewhich emerald.map`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following error when I run sudo updmap-sys --enable-map=emerald.map:
Unknown option: enable-map
Try "updmap --help" for more information.

Comment: @diedro Sorry, typo. Should've been `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map`. You might need the absolute path from `kpsewhich emerald.map`.

Comment: I moved in the folder where is located emerald.map and then I run sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map. That is "usr/local/share/texmf/emerald/fonts/map/dvips". Then I run sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map. This is the outcome:
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: The strange thing is also that when I run the command "kpsewhich emerald.map" I get nothing in the terminal.

Comment: @diedro Sounds like the file might not have been indexed. Does `find /usr/local/ -name "emerald.map" -print` find the absolute path to the file?

Comment: here the outcomes: /usr/local/share/texmf/emerald/fonts/map/dvips/emerald.map

Comment: Now it seems better. In "/usr/local/share/texmf" I have a file named ls-R. Still, when I try to compile my tex file i have "emerald.sty" not found

Comment: @diedro According to [these instructions,](https://www.tug.org/mactex/TeXLive2018+Changes.pdf) installing to the local tree in `/usr/local` should work. (I would never put TeX packages in your user library unless you can’t avoid it, e.g. you are on a shared computer with no root access. TeX Live has a serious bug where user map files **hide** updates to the system maps, rather than adding to them.)

Comment: @diedro Unfortunately, I can’t duplicate your problem. If you previously tried to install the files to another location, please make sure they have been removed and the file list of your local library updated.

Comment: I have just apply purge to texlive and applied again the procedure. I do not understand. shall I apply the procedure not to local but in another location?

Comment: Is the problem that I ma using kile and pdflatex?

Comment: @diedro I don’t know, but something’s unusual about your installation. I edited in a link to the latest version of Emerald City Fontwerks’ download page I could find on the Internet Archive. You should be able to download the TrueType version from there.

Comment: Maybe it is something related to Ubuntu user vs system. What about to apply the suggested procedure in the system? Another question. The fact that kile does not find emerald.sty when it compiles could it mean that is a problem related to the location of the emerald packege?

Comment: Other information: /usr/local/share/texmf was empty. All the information seems to be in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist. Could this be relevant?

Comment: I have more or less solve the problem by using this statement of the *.tex fil:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\augiefamily}{%
  \fontfamily{augie}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaugie}{\augiefamily}

However, I have to use "\augiefamily" in each frame

Comment: @diedro Ah, so the problem was with your `beamer` theme. Using the `professionalfonts` option and the `serif` font theme should work.

Comment: I don't have understood what do you mean. I have edit the question in order to show my solution. What do you mean?