# Installing the emerald package (a font package) under Windows and TeXLive

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing-fonts

- I want to use the [`emerald`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emerald) package under **Windows** and **TeXLive**. It is only available in MiKTeX according to its CTAN entry.
- According to an old post ([Installing Emerald fonts: TeXlive won't find font files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248464)) the instructions in the readme are outdated.
- **Q:** What is the proper way to install `emerald` package under **Windows** and **TeXLive** in 2021?

Comment: It might be faster (5 mins?) to download and install the actual .ttf files themselves, and use them as system fonts under xelatex/lualatex, rather than trying a manual install of a pdftex support package. (e.g., just at random, 25 Emerald City Fontwerks fonts in 16 families are listed at dafonts: https://www.dafont.com/emerald-city-fontwerks.d105).

Comment: @Cicada Thanks for the proposal. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592980/use-of-emerald-fonts-in-ubuntu-and-locate-font-folder) will work, but run the commands from an Administrator prompt, rather than `sudo`.

Find your local TeX tree with `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` in TeX Live, or the MikTeX console.  Unpack the emerald archive to there.  It will likely be `C:\texlive\texmf-local\`.

Run `texhash` to update the file index, then `updmap-sys --enable Map=emerald.map` to update the system font map.  (Never `updmap --user`.  It’s a trap.)  You can now `\usepackage{emerald}`.

Alternatively, download [the the TrueType version of the Emerald fonts.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719055112/http://www.speakeasy.org/%7Eecf/alphabet.htm)  You will want to install them for all users, or save them to a subdirectory of your local TeX tree, such as `texmf-local/fonts/opentype/emerald/`.

Comment: Thanks! And I laughed about "it's a trap"

Comment: Hello, when I run the command `texhash`, I have this error: `Cannot open C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R to write.` How to do?

Comment: @AndréC Necromancy: Make sure 1: that you don’t have your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory set somewhere else, 2: that the directory exists and 3: that you have write permission to it.